# Close point of approch detection

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, optimization, geometry, spatial

I have a large set of 3rd order polynomials in 3D.

in matrix form

> Pn = [1,t,t<sup>2</sup>,t<sup>4</sup>]*[An]
>
> `[Pn]` and `[An]` are `1xN` and `4xN` matrices respectively

each function has a weight Wn. I want to, for some `n, m, T` and `t0` find the first `t` where `t>t0` such that

> (Wn*Wm) * |Pn-Pm|<sup>-2</sup> > T

aside from a the O(n<sup>2</sup>) "try everything" approach I'm not even sure where to start, For that matter, I'm not shure how to answer this even for the known n & m.

Any ideas

Edit:

- the set size is on the order of 10-1000
- the weight's are distributed ~ logarithmically (very few large, many small)
- this test would be in an inner loop of an n-body simulator so it would get run a lot
- versions that do well (amortized) at finding a new answer after one path is altered are a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing if this is solvable through analytic means, there are many approaches to searching a space and trying to find any t that meets that criteria.

Genetic algorithms, simulated annealing and other algorithms for optimization spring to mind.

Comment: Those might work well for the continues part of the problem (given 2 functions find a close approach) but that still doesn't handle the discreet part (which 2 to pick). Might be a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

OK to seed the pot:

- Using some form of "close pair finder" algorithm seed a heap with those pairs at t0 and other times.
- Pull the closest pair found
- if close enough and sooner than the best so far, keep
- find if they are closer or further apart
- split the difference between the current pair and the next one in on the "closer" side and add that the the heap.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

How large is N?  Is an exhaustive search even possible?

I'd ask the question on the [numpy](http://groups.google.com/group/Numpy-discussion) or [scipy](http://groups.google.com/group/scipy-user) discussion boards and brush up on your python skills.  My bet is you could probably turn this into a minimisation problem and use fmin or [BFGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BFGS) or some other bounded quasi-Newton algorithm to find a reasonable minimum.  Perhaps minimise the difference between t and T.  Unless there is something weird in your matrices it looks like your search space may at least be continuous.

Since you mention closest point of approach in your title [check this post out](http://groups.google.com/group/Numpy-discussion/browse_thread/thread/0d4f89f885f7b83b#) on the numpy board.